# How do I fix crontab executing a python subprocess incorrectly?

Tags: python, cron, subprocess

I am running a python file that, among other things, opens and runs a subprocess that runs the 'speedtest-cli --simple' command line. When executed normally, this works fine and returns the ping, download and upload, but when called with crontab, the values are blank. Values are normally only blank if an internet connection can not be established.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#Speed test opens a subprocess that runs the speed test from the command terminal, returning ping, download and upload speeds. 
def speedTest():
    cmd = 'speedtest-cli --simple' #Command to be run in terminal
    envi = os.environ
    response = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=envi, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).stdout.read().decode('utf-8')#Run subprocess
    try: #Try to pull relevant data
        ping = re.findall('Ping:\s(.*?)\s', response, re.MULTILINE)
        download = re.findall('Download:\s(.*?)\s', response, re.MULTILINE)
        upload = re.findall('Upload:\s(.*?)\s', response, re.MULTILINE)
    except: #-2 Error code for Speedtest Error, entered if pull fails (NOTE: even if the pull isn't able to connect, the try should still succeed. This case should not be entered.)
        print('failed')
        ping = ['-2']
        download = ['-2']
        upload = ['-2']
        errflag = -2 #Set errflag to -2 to track error
        pass
    if (ping == []): #-3 Error code for Speedtest Connection Error. Entered if pull is successful but connection could not be made.
        ping.append('-3')
        download.append('-3')
        upload.append('-3')
        errflag = -3 #Set errflag to -3 to track error
    return [ping[0],download[0],upload[0]] #Return ping, download, and upload.
```

the crontab that runs it is shown here

```
 Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# 
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
# 
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').
# 
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# 
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# 
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# 
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command

* * * * * /home/pi/datatest.py >> out.txt 2>&1
```

Any suggestions on how to obtain output values in crontab would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check the `PATH` environment variable in the `crond` environment. I bet that `speedtest-cli` is not in its `PATH`.

Comment: @MichaelRuth how would I do that? I am incredibly new to using crontab.

Comment: As indicated by @MichaelRuth your PATH in cron and many other environment variables may not be populated the same as an interactive shell. In your shell do `which speedtest-cli` and then just use the full path for it as your cmd.

Comment: @SuperKnight106, since you're new to crontab, know that it runs under the root user and therefore inherits the root user's environment. The three most common solutions to your problem are to use the full path of the executable, as @Amos Baker commented; use `su` to change to a user with the desired environment; or to set the `PATH` variable in the crontab file.

Comment: @AmosBaker thank you! I am finally getting outputs running it from Crontab. The `which` command is incredibly helpful. Much appreciated!

Comment: @SuperKnight106 `whereis` is related but more generically finds any match on your PATH which can also be incredibly useful.